# Unable to test multiple logEvent message in unit tests in Log4j2

Tags: java, maven, junit, mockito, log4j2

I am having log4j2 with slf4j but getting same log message.
Provided the sample code. Getting Mutable Log Event in Argument Capture Log Event object.
Count is giving correct but same message gets repeated in when I call getAllValues() method.
Using Mockito, junit and log4j2. I debugged a lot but could find that what should be change to get correct log message in test class. I can see some other alternatives to test the same behaviour but I want to know where is the error in this piece of code.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class ApplicationLog {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationLog.class);
    public void sayHi(){
        //System.out.println("hi");
        logger.warn("Say Hi");
        logger.warn("Say Hello");
    }
}
```

**Test** **class**

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.*;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;



@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ApplicationLogTest {
    private ApplicationLog applicationLog = new ApplicationLog();



    @Mock
    private Appender mockAppender;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<LogEvent> captorLoggingEvent;

 
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
       
        final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
        Mockito.reset(mockAppender);
  
       config.getRootLogger().addAppender(mockAppender, null, null);
        Mockito.when(mockAppender.getName()).thenReturn("MockAppender");
        Mockito.when(mockAppender.isStarted()).thenReturn(true);
        Mockito.when(mockAppender.isStopped()).thenReturn(false);
        ctx.updateLoggers();


    }

    @After
    public void teardown() {
        ((LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false)).getConfiguration().getRootLogger().removeAppender(null);
      
    }

    @Test
    public void firstTest(){
        Configurator.setRootLevel(Level.TRACE);
    

        applicationLog.sayHi();
        verify(mockAppender, times(2)).append((LogEvent) captorLoggingEvent.capture());
        String message = captorLoggingEvent.getAllValues().get(0).getMessage().getFormattedMessage();
**// Not getting Say Hi but getting Say Hello**
        assertThat(message, is("Say Hi"));
    }
 
}
```

**Dependencies**

```
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>${org.log4j-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${org.log4j-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>${org.log4j-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: For testing purposes there is a [`ListAppender`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/release-2.x/log4j-core/src/test/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/test/appender/ListAppender.java) in `log4j-core`'s test jar.

Comment: Thanks @PiotrP.Karwasz. Could you please what is issue with above code. I am getting the log events but last log event is overridden to the all log events under captorLoggingEvent.